# Archive of Distributed Code Jam problems anyone?

Tags: archive

While reading the books on designing distributed systems, it came to me that one helpful thing to do could be trying practicing problems from Distributed Code Jam held by Google in 2015-2018.

I was rather disappointed founding out that not only DCG is over but that all the materials of past contests were removed. Nothing is left by the official URL: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/past-competitions/distributed

I pinged them by email w/o any reaction so far.

Does anyone accidentally have these materials (problems and solutions) or any part of them archived?

Answer (score 1):

Try at https://github.com/google/coding-competitions-archive. The announcement blog post for the archive repository is https://developers.googleblog.com/2023/05/celebrate-googles-coding-competitions.html.

Here is a Web Archive version of the page you linked, https://web.archive.org/web/20210419174656/https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/past-competitions/distributed.